# Using sed on Mac OS 10 to replace tab character in text files

Tags: macos, sed, tabs, special-characters

I've been searching here for quite some time, and though I have found some really good info, nothing quite zeros in on my issue. Short-n-sweet, I'm using sed on Mac OS 10.11 to try and replace the tab character with the  pipe character. All the info I have found on this so far, the syntax may work on other platforms but not on Mac OS 10.11. I know sed works on 10.11 as I can replace normal, standard characters all day long and even some punctuation like a comma. And yes, I have tried using `\t`. The sed string I found that works with standard characters is the following:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/,/|/g' /Users/username/Desktop/TABs2PIPE.txt
```

When I use `\t` in place of the `,` in the above string, it simply replaces all the lowercase `t` in the file.

So, any other Macheads out there who have gotten this to work I really would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

OSX `sed` is BSD-derived; this lineage of `sed` has never accepted `\t` as notation for the TAB character, IIRC.  If your shell is `bash` (which is the default on OSX), try this instead:

```
sed -i '' -e $'s/\t/|/g' file_to_process.txt
```

`$'...'` is a bash extension; it's a `'...'` quoted word, but C-style backslash escapes are interpreted within.  From the bash manpage:

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word expands to
>   *string*, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by  the
>   ANSI C standard.

So, `sed` will see `-e` `s/ /|/g` where the gap between the first two spaces is a literal TAB character, and it should do the Right Thing with that.

If your shell is *not* bash, you can probably type a literal tab character yourself by typing control-V and then TAB.

Answer (score 1):

The way **sed** handles backslash-T is certainly unexpected if you haven't encountered it before!

This works:

```
sed -i s/\<CTRL-V><TAB>/\|/g text.txt
```

Where <CTRL-V> and <TAB> are the actual keys pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kurt. I already tried that but terminal won't let me paste a real tab.

Comment: @MacDudeDonny *Control* V, not ⌘V.  (The control key should be at the far left of the row with the space bar, and should say either "control" or "ctrl" on it, depending on which keyboard you have.)